# In Magento 2 how can I return a collection without the top 10% and bottom 10%?

Tags: magento2, collection, filter

I am looking to return a subset of reviews for example but discard the top x% and bottom x%

I could do it with an SQL query such as

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT review_date, review_score,  @r:= @r + 1 AS rownum
  FROM review_detail, (SELECT @r:=0) x
  ORDER BY review_score
) x
WHERE rownum > @r * .1
  AND rownum <= @r * .9
;
```

However I'm struggling to understand how I can order the collection and add a new field for the row number and then be able to order and sort it using the syntax within magento

when you get a collection is the row number updated so that if I sort by rating I can then address the row number?

I'm guessing I'd have to use `Zend_Db_Expr` to create the new field for row number sorted by review score then use `array("from" => $fromValue, "to" => $toValue)` in an `addFilterToField` Statement to return the collection

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT : I've tried doing it by using limit and offset but this destroys the pagination on the screen but returns the correct data

```
 } elseif ($condition == Filter::EXCLUDE) {
            if ($value !== 'None') {
                $percentage = (float)$value;
                $current_size = $reviewCollection->getSize();
                $start_pos = round($current_size * ($percentage/100));
                $offset = $current_size - (2*$start_pos);
                $reviewCollection->getSelect()->limit($offset,$start_pos);
                $reviewCollection->getItems();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always just run the raw SQL:

```
$dbConnection = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
        ->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection')
        ->getConnection();

$result = $dbConnection->fetchAll("
    SELECT * FROM
    (
      SELECT review_date, review_score,  @r:= @r + 1 AS rownum
      FROM review_detail, (SELECT @r:=0) x
      ORDER BY review_score
    ) x
    WHERE rownum > @r * .1
      AND rownum <= @r * .9
");
```

And then looping over the results you can build a new structure or use the data returned:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    //$result['review_date'];
    //$result['review_score'];
}
```

Comment: Hi Barry I'd love to but I need it to also preserve other filters that already exist on the collection, I'm using a toolbar and can filter by helpful etc and also sort, I really need to add it to the existing collection, unless I use that to build an array and then filter by the review_id on the existing collection.

Comment: "unless I use that to build an array and then filter by the review_id on the existing collection", that would have been my suggestion but was unsure the size of numbers that would be relevant

Comment: i've resigned myself to the fact that until I update my version of Ubunto and therefore the MariaDb so that I can use windows expressions, there is no other way unless someone else has any ideas?

Comment: Solved it but had to basically run the raw sql then use that to generate an array and apply it as a filter to the original collection.